# Preserving quotes with Papa Parse

Tags: papaparse

I'm using the Papa parse Library but can't seem to get it to keep quotes.

I tried this:

```
var parseMe = '"my","header","row","is","here"\r\n"one","two","three","four","five"\r\n"six","seven","eight","nine","ten"';

var pConfig = {"skipEmptyLines":true,
 "delimiter":",",
 "quotes":false}

 console.log(JSON.stringify(Papa.parse( parseMe, pConfig ).data));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w9wwqwx/

But no luck. I get back:

```
[["my","header","row","is","here"],["one","two","three","four","five"],["six","seven","eight","nine","ten"]]
```

But I was expecting something like:

```
[["\"my"\","\"header"\","\"row"\","\"is"\","\"here"\"],.....
```

e.g. with all the quotes still in the output.

I'd thought setting quotes to false would get papa parse to keep the double quotes inside the strings but no luck. I don't want to have to escape the quotes if I can help it. I suppose I could just put them back in :P.

Answer (score -1):

By default PapaParse uses " as quoteChar, so if the fields are enquoted with " this value is removed. If you want to preserve the " caracter when parsing the file you must use a diferent quoteChar (for example ').

This will do the trick:

```
var parseMe = '"my","header","row","is","here"\r\n"one","two","three","four","five"\r\n"six","seven","eight","nine","ten"';

var pConfig = {"skipEmptyLines":true,  "delimiter":",", "quoteChar": "'"}

 console.log(JSON.stringify(Papa.parse( parseMe, pConfig ).data));
```

Comment: Thanks :)!. What should I do if I want there to be no enclosure? quotes=false doesn't seem to do anything. Come to think of it, what is the 'quotes' parameter for? Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed the quotes config it's only used for unparsing files and not for parsing in order to force the output to be all enclosed with quotes